# Cordova/Phonegap build Google play target api26 not working with old android phones

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

So yesterday I did an quick update to My app on the android Store Scribble Jumper.
The google play store only allowed my to update if I switched api level to 26 which is terrible for me because My app is playable on all levels I dont want to have this limit to only new phones.

I use cordova to update my codes.
In My config.xml I updates this which allowed Me to update my app
 
the value was 14 before and it worked with all level of androids.
the rest of the config.xml is as follows

```
<widget>
  <name>Scribble Jumper</name>
  <author href="http://Bruno58.com" 
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>
  <!-- Recent changes for 0.0.3 -->



  <platform name="android" >
  <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
  <icon src="res/android/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
  <icon src="res/android/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
  <icon src="res/android/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
  <icon src="res/android/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />

<!--                                  this is the 1.0.5 update for android for splash screens                                             -->
<splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/splash-port-ldpi.png"/>
<splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/splash-port-mdpi.png"/>
<splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/splash-port-hdpi.png"/>
<splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png"/>
<splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/splash-port-xxhdpi.png"/>
<splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/splash-port-xxxhdpi.png"/>
<splash src="splash.png"/> <!--this is an update for 1.0.8-->
<!--                                  this is the 1.0.5 update for android for splash screens                                             -->


  </platform>
 <!-- Recent changes for 0.0.3 -->
 <!-- Recent changes for 0.0.4 -->
<!--<plugin spec="https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro" /> this is the new git im using 12/1/17-->
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" /><!--this is the new update for 5/29/18 for in app web-->

<!-- this needs to be updated for ios<plugin spec="https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro.git#007b791" />-->

<!--<plugin spec="https://github.com/ratson/cordova-plugin-admob-free" />  this is for admob free next update to play with-->

<plugin spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git#5ca43e8" />    <!--        This is also for the splashscreen update 1.0.5                  -->



<!--      IOS Changes scribble jumper 1.0.0         --> <!--  1.0.2 removed and fixed paths for ios  -->
<platform name="ios">
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<icon src="res/ios/icon-1024.png" width="1024" height="1024"/>
<icon src="res/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29"/>
<icon src="res/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>
<icon src="res/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>
<icon src="res/ios/icon-small-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
<icon src="res/ios/icon-small-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
<icon src="res/ios/icon-small-40@3x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
<icon src="res/ios/icon-small-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
<icon src="res/ios/icon-small-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
<icon src="res/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
<icon src="res/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
<icon src="res/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
<icon src="res/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
<icon src="res/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
<icon src="res/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
<icon src="res/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
<icon src="res/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
<icon src="res/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>
<icon src="res/ios/icon-167.png" width="167" height="167"/>
<icon src="res/ios/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" height="167"/>


<!--                                  this is the 1.0.5 update for android for splash screens                                             -->
<splash src="res/screens/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
<splash src="res/screens/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
<splash src="res/screens/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
<splash src="res/screens/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
<splash src="res/screens/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
<splash src="res/screens/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
<splash src="res/screens/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>


<!--                                  this is the 1.0.5 update for android for splash screens                                             -->

    </platform>
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="true" />


<!--      IOS Changes scribble jumper 1.0.0         --> <!--  1.0.2 removed and fixed paths for ios  -->

 <!-- Recent changes for 0.0.4 -->


  <access origin="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>


  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
  </platform>

  <!--      IOS Changes scribble jumper 1.0.0         -->
 <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />

    </platform>

<!--      IOS Changes scribble jumper 1.0.0         -->
</widget>

`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Solutions Should of read a little more I simply specified the lowest sdk I wanted to target plus the highest too BOOMMMM Fixed my app works on all Levels of androids!!!

android-maxSdkVersion(integer) 
Default: Not Specified 
Sets the maxSdkVersion attribute of the  tag in the project's AndroidManifest.xml (see here).
android-minSdkVersion(integer) 
Default: Dependent on cordova-android Version 
Sets the minSdkVersion attribute of the  tag in the project's AndroidManifest.xml (see here).

Answer (score 0):

Google has changed its policy recently (due to security reasons) where any new apps must target API 26 or above. AFAIK, that corresponds to Android Oreo and above. So far there doesn't seem to be any workaround to this problem.

Comment: Hi I  found the solution all you have to do is target the sdk26 while just making target devices lowest at api14 and highest at api27 and its workin for me I just did my update and my app is available on all devices again.